# Sitecore Preview Images wrong path

Tags: image, sitecore

I have noticed something very wierd with one of our sites. I insert an image in the Rich Text editor which looks like this

```
<img width="100%" src="~/media/6BC8DAA4359041448098696D1DA10A03.ashx" alt="abcd" />
```

I have published the image on the page and it works fine, i can see the image.

when i inspect the element i see

```
<img width="100%" alt="abcd" src="~/media/myFolder/Ready For Web/News/Airtrain.ashx">
```

but when i preview the same page i don't see the image. This is the html that i see

```
<img width="100%" src="~/media/media library/myFolder/Ready For Web/News/Airtrain.ashx" alt="Airtrain and PayPal make travelling a breeze">
```

notice the extra /media library/ in the path and i am not sure why thats happening and how to resolve this.

Comment: Are you using a non default LinkManager? In preview the url is different but should work. /sitecore/shell/~/media/myFolder/Ready For Web/News/Airtrain.ashx

Comment: You could always do a little hack, and do a String.Replace on the sentence "media library", before you pass it to the DOM. That would in theory work the same as without preview, but might be a solution that aren't gonna be stable in the long run.

Comment: Kevin, that's what I have done, but it is not a long term solution.

Comment: Jan, no it is the default LinkManager